# Switchable designs/layouts in React for the whole application

Tags: reactjs, layout, themes

Our application front-end is implemented in React. It has a theming, like switching white/black themes. But now we need to implement a completely new design, while keeping an option to switch to old design. New design in general has different layout for most of pages, so it's not only about CSS.

I wonder if there're some patterns/workable solutions for implementing multiple layouts for the same page in React, so that it was easy to switch between them. Code should remain supportable, of course, with minimum need to reimplement logic changes for each layout in further.